# T-SQL elegant solution to divide a numeric value to multiple accounts

Tags: t-sql, division

I have a problem that I believe has a perfectly elegant solution, but would like some help.

So I have a table of persons and a numerical value. Besides that, there is a table with the rules of division of that value (per person) to multiple accounts, rule can be either a max value or a percentage of the value.

This is a simplified version of these tables.

```
Persons(PersonID int, Value decimal)

Account(AccountID int, PersonID int)

Distribution(AccountID int, MaxValue decimal Null, Percentage decimal null)
```

At some point I need to divide those numerical values to a third table - that holds the account and value divided to that account.

```
AccountValues(AccountID int, AccountValue decimal)
```

The count of the accounts (per person) is not fixed. In the distribution table - if both of the distribution values are null - all the left over value goes to that account.
The order of distribution is by their ID's.

The data could look something like this.

```
Persons  table
PersonID    Value
    1            1000,00
    2            2000,00
    3            5000,00
    4            500,00

Accounts table
AccountID   PersonID
1            1
2            1
3            2
4            2
5            2
6            3
7            3
8            4
9            4
10           4

Distribution table
AccountID    MaxValue    Percentage
1            500,00          null
2            null            null
3            null            0,5
4            null            0,2
5            null            null
6            1000,00         null
7            null            null
8            2000,00         null
9            null            0,2
10           null            null
```

Still a bit new to T-SQL so need help with the simplest and most efficient solution.

So for now I'm thinking of 3 possible solutions.
1. The least elegant - count the max number of accounts per person and do a loop that many times.
2. Cursors - the best way perhaps?
3. CTE recursion (about which I know nothing about)

Comment: Cursors are almost never the best solution

Comment: Is there a missing `PersonID` in one or both of the other tables? I'm not sure I follow your narrative well enough. Maybe if you could add some sample data (between 5 and 10 rows showing a few variations) and expected results, I could give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a CTE. There might be a smarter way to do the totalling, but I think this works.

Data setup:

```
declare @Persons table (PersonID int not null,Value decimal(18,4) not null)
insert into @Persons(PersonID,Value) values
(1,1000.00),
(2,2000.00),
(3,5000.00),
(4,500.00)

declare @Accounts table (AccountID int not null,PersonID int not null)
insert into @Accounts(AccountID,PersonID) values
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(4,2),
(5,2),
(6,3),
(7,3),
(8,4),
(9,4),
(10,4)

declare @Distribution table (AccountID int not null,MaxValue decimal(18,4) null,Percentage decimal(6,5) null)
insert into @Distribution (AccountID,MaxValue,Percentage) values
(1,500.00,null),
(2,null,null),
(3,null,0.5),
(4,null,0.2),
(5,null,null),
(6,1000.00,null),
(7,null,null),
(8,2000.00,null),
(9,null,0.2),
(10,null,null)

declare @AccountValues table (AccountID int not null,Value decimal(18,4) null)
```

Actual query:

```
;With DisbValues as (
    select
        a.AccountID,
        p.PersonID,
        CASE
            WHEN d.MaxValue is not null then d.MaxValue
            WHEN d.Percentage is not null then d.Percentage * p.Value
        END as Value,
        p.Value as TotalAvailable
    from
        @Distribution d
            inner join
        @Accounts a
            on
                d.AccountID = a.AccountID
            inner join
        @Persons p
            on
                a.PersonID = p.PersonID
), CumulativeValues as (
    select
        AccountID,
        PersonID,
        Value,
        COALESCE((select SUM(Value) from DisbValues d2 where d2.PersonID = d.PersonID and d2.AccountID < d.AccountID),0) as PrevValue,
        TotalAvailable
    from
        DisbValues d
)
insert into @AccountValues (AccountID,Value)
select
    AccountID,
    CASE WHEN PrevValue < TotalAvailable THEN
        CASE WHEN PrevValue + Value < TotalAvailable THEN Value --Entirely satisfied
        ELSE TotalAvailable - PrevValue --Partially satisfied
        END
    ELSE
        0 --Not satisfied
    END
from CumulativeValues
```

The first CTE (`DisbValues`) eliminates the need to think in terms of percentages (I've assumed that we're working with a percentage of the total value available, not of the remainder when trying to satisfy a particular account). The second CTE (`CumulativeValues`) then adds up all of the values that earlier accounts would require to be filled.

We can then, in the final query, break things down into 3 cases, as indicated by the comments.

Comment: @user1659425 - No problem. There's only one issue with it - I came back to look at it just now and couldn't work out *myself* how it dealt with the `NULL` values. I might add an explanation (once I've worked it out myself)